# Path issues C#.net Image

Tags: c#, image, path

So I am trying to take a picture that i save to my server in a temp images folder and I want to then later on take it and apply some System.Drawing stuff to it. I know that the image is being saved correctly since I can go to `http://localhost/TempImages/x.png` but when i try to create the Image from `Image z = Image.FromFile("TempImage/x.png");` its giving me a file not found exception. I tried all sorts of Path. operations but none I tried seemed to work. Can someone give me some help/insight into what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Image z = Image.FromFile("/TempImage/x.png");
```

To indicate that `TempImage` is a folder and not a file.

Comment: Thanks this works nicely, gotta love programming one back slash and you lose your mind for an half an hour =)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned a server, so I'm thinking that you're doing something with a web server. In that case, you need to get the full physical path to your image, based on where the root location is on your server.

You call will look something like:

```
Image z = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("TempImage/x.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an absolute path like this.

```
Image image1 = Image.FromFile("c:\\FakePhoto1.jpg");
```

Or

```
Image image1 = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("http://localhost/TempImages/x.png"));
```